# Adding 7 days in PHP calculates time incorrectly

Tags: php, strtotime

When I do this:

```
$date = "2017-02-06 21:30:00";
$end_date = "2017-02-28 21:30:00";
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo $date."<br />";
    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
2017-02-06 21:30:00
2017-02-13 09:30:00
2017-02-20 09:30:00
2017-02-27 09:30:00
```

Any idea why + 7 day is short by 12 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is difference in

1. show hours 01 through 12

   ```
   date('h');
   ```
2. show hours 00 through 23

   ```
   date('H');
   ```

More info about it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

your code should be:

```
$date = "2017-02-06 21:30:00";
$end_date = "2017-02-28 21:30:00";
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo $date."<br />";
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Comment: Doh. Thanks. I should have spotted that. Dumb error on my part.

Comment: such stuff happens from time to time :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not, you're displaying it with :

```
date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$time); // as h stands for 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros  01 through 12
```

Use H instead :

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time); // as H stands for 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros  00 through 23
```